# How to construct a truth table

Tags: boolean-algebra, digital-circuits

Yes this is a homework problem, but I only need help setting it up, there are 7 parts to the question once I set it up:

> We want to build a function Y = 2X + 3 where X denotes a 3-bit
>   unsigned value(x2x1x0) and Y = y4..y0 is a 5-bit value in hardware.
>   Contruct its truth table where input bits are x2, x1, and x0 and
>   output bits are y4 through y0.

The homework problem then asks for a bunch of other things which I can get. I just don't understand the question, how do you create a truth table based on a function and these input bits?

Should the truth table look something like this?

```
x2 x1 x0 y4 y3 y2 y1 y0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1 
0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1 
0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1 
0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1 
1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1 
1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1 
1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

For each of the eight inputs, you compute the output. You will get a table with eight rows and $3+5=8$ columns, containing the three input bits and the five output bits.

Comment: Edited my post, is that the truth table we're looking for?

Comment: Yes, you got the idea.